# How to measure cross-covariance in mathematica

Tags: distributions

In matlab cross-covariance is given by
[c,lags] = xcov(x,maxlags,'coeff');
How can I measure in Mathematica?

Comment: Try to use Covariance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

a Rewrite of my answer in an effort to recreate Matlab's xcov function.  I'm using [this documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcov.html#bub5iaz-2) as reference.  I'd appreciate any code review, in particular how the scale options are implemented since I've seen conflicting documentation.  First, the function:

```
Clear[CrossCovariance];
Options[CrossCovariance] = {"Lag" -> All, "Scale" -> None};
CrossCovariance::lagtoolarge = 
  "The option for Lag (`1`) is greater than the length of the Lists \
provided. Using maximum possible Lag";
CrossCovariance[x_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[Length@Dimensions[x] == 1, CrossCovariance[x, x, opts],
  CrossCovariance[Sequence @@ #, opts] & /@ Tuples[x, 2]]
CrossCovariance[x_List, y_List, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{nmax, xlist, ylist, scale, s},
  xlist = x;
  ylist = y;
  (* Pad the shorter list with zeros *)
  If[Length@xlist > Length@ylist, 
   ylist = PadRight[ylist, Length@xlist]];
  If[Length@xlist < Length@ylist, 
   xlist = PadRight[xlist, Length@ylist]];
  
  (* Implement Lag option, Fixes non-integer and negative lag values *)
      
  nmax = If[OptionValue["Lag"] =!= All, 
    IntegerPart@Abs@OptionValue["Lag"], Length@xlist - 1];
  If[nmax > Length@xlist - 1, (nmax = Length@xlist - 1; 
    Message[CrossCovariance::lagtoolarge, OptionValue["Lag"]])];
  
  (* Implement the Scale option, None does nothing, 
  "biased" is a biased estimate, 
  "unbiased" is an unbiased estimate and "coeff" normalizes the list so that \
  autocovariance with zero lag is equal to 1. All else is assumed to be None *)
  scale = 1;
  s[n_] := Switch[
    OptionValue["Scale"],
    "unbiased", Length@xlist,
    "biased", (Length@xlist - Abs[n]),
    "coeff", 1/Covariance[xlist, ylist],
    _, 1];
  
  (* Create CrossCovariance table *)
  Table[s[n] Covariance[xlist, RotateRight[ylist, n]], {n, -nmax, nmax, 1}]]
```

Now some data.  `s1` is random, `s2` is `s1` shifted by 50 places and `s3` is a few short of `s2`; `data` is real periodic sunspot data from here

```
SeedRandom[1234];
s1 = RandomReal[1, 150];
s2 = RotateRight[s1, 50];
s3 = Drop[s2, 25];
data = Flatten@
   Import["http://w3eos.whoi.edu/12.747/notes/lect06/SUNSPOTS.DAT"];
```

The random data and its shifted counterpart

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compute the noramlized autocovariance of the the randomized data

```
ListLinePlot[CrossCovariance[s1, "Scale" -> "coeff"], 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {-150, 150}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lists of unequal length are dealt with using zero padding

```
ListLinePlot[CrossCovariance[s1, s3], PlotRange -> All, 
 DataRange -> {-150, 150}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compute the biased estimates of the autocovariance and mutual cross-covariance sequences.

```
ListLinePlot[CrossCovariance[{s1, s2}, "Scale" -> "biased"], 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {-150, 150}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Limit the range of shifted values with "Lag".  End user needs to address the symmetry around the zero-shift if desired.

```
cvdata = CrossCovariance[data, "Lag" -> 588, "Scale" -> "coeff"];
ListLinePlot[cvdata[[1178/2 ;;]], PlotRange -> All, 
 DataRange -> {0, 588/12}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Previous version

As far as I can tell, *Mathematica* does not have a cross-covariance function built in.  However, if we take a look at what cross-covariance is from [here](http://w3eos.whoi.edu/12.747/notes/lect06/l06s02.html) and [there](http://www.statlect.com/varian2.htm) on the internet, we can come up with a method which might help you out.  I'll use the first reference, which contains some example sunspot data:

```
data = Flatten@Import[
   "http://w3eos.whoi.edu/12.747/notes/lect06/SUNSPOTS.DAT"];
```

The cross-covariance of this data set (or more precisely, the auto-covariance) is the Covariance of the original dataset and a time-shifted copy.  We can get at the time shifted copy using the following:

```
 ListLinePlot[Table[Covariance[data[[n ;;]], data[[;; -n]]], {n, 1, 588, 1}], 
   DataRange -> {0, 49}]
```

[image]

As expected, we see the largest covariance when there is no lag, which makes sense since the data should match up with itself perfectly.  We see local maxima in the time-lagged covariance with a periodicity of about 11 years, which is consistent with the 11-year sunspot cycle we have all learned about.

Finding the cross-covariance of two stochastic processes would function the same way assuming the time steps and dataset lengths are equal.

And just for fun, compare the auto-covariance of the sunspot data with normally distributed data with the same mean and standard deviation:

```
datar = RandomVariate[
   NormalDistribution[Mean@data, StandardDeviation@data], 
   Length@data];
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Covariance[datar[[n ;;]], datar[[;; -n]]], {n, 1, 588, 1}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 49}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

We see that the auto-covariance very quickly drops to 0, indicating that there is no signal contained in this dataset.

Comment: Thank you #bobthechemist for your effort and help.